# query hanging on begin tran

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am executing the below but its hanging for several minutes , checking `sp_who` saying the session is running , no blocking

```
DECLARE @intFlag INT
SET @intFlag = 1
WHILE (@intFlag <=3) 

BEGIN tran
    SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
    INSERT INTO EX_EMPLOYEE (TV_CODE) VALUES (@intFlag)
 commit tran

GO
```

however if i remove the tran it commits and finishes

```
DECLARE @intFlag INT
SET @intFlag = 1
WHILE (@intFlag <=3) 

BEGIN 
    SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
    INSERT INTO EX_EMPLOYEE (TV_CODE) VALUES (@intFlag)
 commit 

GO
```

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: put begin tran before your while loop

Comment: @Triv why in the first its hanging but the first it commited quickly ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you loop

```
WHILE (@intFlag <=3)  BEGIN tran
```

never end. Infinitely "BEGIN TRAN"

> WHILE Sets a condition for the repeated execution of an SQL statement
>   or statement block.

Use BEGIN..END for group

```
DECLARE @intFlag INT
SET @intFlag = 1
WHILE (@intFlag <=3) 
BEGIN
    BEGIN tran
    SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
    INSERT INTO EX_EMPLOYEE (TV_CODE) VALUES (@intFlag)
    commit tran
END
```

or

```
DECLARE @intFlag INT
SET @intFlag = 1
BEGIN TRANSACTION
WHILE (@intFlag <=3) 
BEGIN

    SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
    INSERT INTO EX_EMPLOYEE (TV_CODE) VALUES (@intFlag)

END
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
   COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: @Moudiz: Think of BEGIN as more like a bracket.